# Network Change event registration failed in MAC OS X 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: c++, macos, networking, osx-lion

I tried to register network_change event in MAC OS X 10.7 (lion) by the following code:

```
#define kNotifySCNetworkChange "com.apple.system.config.network_change"
void init()
{

   status = notify_register_check(kNotifySCNetworkChange, &token);
   if (status != NOTIFY_STATUS_OK)
   {
       cout << "Event Registration failed" <<endl;
   }
   cout << "Event Registration Success" << endl;

}
```

.....

If I use this code in a sample program, it registered successfully.
If I use this in my application, notify_register_check() function returned with **status** 1000000 (NOTIFY_STATUS_FAILED). In addition, the errno returned is 0.

Note: My application is working in Leopard and Snow Leopard with out any issue (registration success)

I googled  for this status but couldn't found the relevant information.
Can anyone just tell me in which scenarios this NOTIFY_STATUS_FAILED is returned?

---

One more thing I observed recently that:
We have used **fork()** system call in my application.
Event registration was success when I tried to register in Parent Process. But Event registration failed in Child process. Why it was failed in Child Process ???  Any Idea!!!

Comment: So the call works in a console app but not in a GUI app?

Comment: Hi @trojanfoe, thanks for your quick reply. My application is not a GUI app.

Comment: In the fork()ed process are you trying to re-register the same event as you already registered in the parent, or are you trying to register the event for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

errno is 0 because the notification API is not a system call, it's a Mach API call. use mach_error () for more details. The fork shouldn't be an issue (it also clones mach ports, for the most part). In fact, the following code works just fine on Mountain Lion:

```
#include <notify.h>
#include <iostream>

#define kNotifySCNetworkChange "com.apple.system.config.network_change"

void init()
{

   int token;
   int status = notify_register_check(kNotifySCNetworkChange, &token);
   if (status != NOTIFY_STATUS_OK)
   {
       std::cout << "Event Registration failed" <<std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << "Event Registration Success" << std::endl;

}

int main()
{
 int rc = fork();
 init();


}
```